# Capture Error and output to log in Bash script

Tags: bash

I have a script which is checking a database for errors based on a text file of record ids.

When an error occurs such as the connection is lost,it writes the offending id ($line) to a log file as well as the error message ($OP).

Problem is the error message is always null although the error is displayed on the console, only the id is written to the log file.

How can I capture the error and also output that to the log file ??

```
while read line
do
    OP=$(mysql $DB -u root --password=$PW -e "select * from properties where hierarchyid = $line")
    printf "\r$line"
    #if [ $? -gt 0 ]; then
    if [[ ! $OP =~ "hierarchyid" ]]; then
        echo
        echo $line $OP >> errors.log
        sleep 10    
        echo
    fi
done < $IDS
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redirect stderr to stdout.

```
OP=$(mysql ... 2>&1)
```